# Regain control over MariaDB functions with "lost" definer due to ip address change

Tags: mariadb

I have a procedure that was created with definer user@'1.1.1.1'.

my ip was changed, and I've lost access to that procedure.

I am able to see them by querying the information schema.

I can see the function exists with the user@newip but I can't see the code or change permissions.

is there a way to "take over" the function ? 
(change it's definer to user@'%' ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SQL command to change the definer or host address.
Hartmut Holzgraefe blogged about this problem and a solution some years ago:

- [Changing the DEFINER of MySQL stored routines etc.](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/changing-the-definer-of-mysql-stored-routines-etc/)
- [Code](https://github.com/hholzgra/change_definer)